# Found a cutstom ActionFilterAttribute in sample project but I can't figure out where it is called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I downloaded a sample MVC application and in it there is a class called "AuthorizationHelper" that inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute` but doing a search of the project I can not find where or how this helper is being called so I am confused on this is being called. I understand what the helper is doing I just can't figure out how it might be called. Here is the code if it helps at all:

```
public class AuthorizationHelper : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string AppLocation = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppLocation"];

        if (AppLocation == "Development")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"controller", "Home"},
                    {"action", "Index"},
                    {"area", ""}
                }
            );
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an action filter which can either be registered in `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs`, or used to decorate controllers, or actions.  If you take a look in `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs`, you might find something like this:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizationHelper());
    }
}
```

In your particular case, `OnActionExecuted` means the filter will be executed *after* an action has been executed but *before* the action result has been executed.

For more information, I'd suggest reading [Understanding Action Filters (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).  Although this link is for older versions of MVC, the only difference is that of how the filter is registered.  Versions of MVC older than MVC 4 would register filters directly within `Global.asax`, rather than in `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and you where right, they are applying at the FilgerConfig file.